# Which interface for __init__ and which for classmethod

Tags: python, interface

I'm working on some Python code, which we want to have a couple of different interfaces, one exposed as the `__init__` and the other via a `@classmethod`.  I'm looking for guidance for which interface should go where.

If we imagine a class that calculates sums of sin waves with different amplitude, phase and frequency, and what is stored in the object is an array of each.  The `__init__` could be:

```py
class waveform:
    def __init__(self, amplitudes, phases, frequencies):
        self.amplitudes = amplitudes
        self.phases = phases
        self.frequencies = frequencies
```

To allow grouping the parameters for a single sin wave together we have added a new object like this:

```py
class singlewave:
    def __init__(self, amplitude, phase, frequency):
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        self.phase = phase
        self.frequency = frequency
```

We could then add a `@classmethod` to waveform making it:

```py
class waveform:
    def __init__(self, amplitudes, phases, frequencies):
        self.amplitudes = amplitudes
        self.phases = phases
        self.frequencies = frequencies

    @classmethod
    def from_waves(cls, listOfWaves):
        amplitudes = [w.amplitude for w in listOfWaves]
        phases = [w.phase for w in listOfWaves]
        frequencies = [w.frequency for w in listOfWaves]
        return cls(amplitudes, phases, frequencies)
```

Alternatively we could go the other way around and have `waveform` look like this:

```py
class waveform:
    def __init__(self, listOfWaves):
        self.amplitudes = [w.amplitude for w in listOfWaves]
        self.phases = [w.phase for w in listOfWaves]
        self.frequencies = [w.frequency for w in listOfWaves]

    @classmethod
    def from_components(cls, amplitudes, phases, frequencies):
        waves = []
        for a, p, f in zip(amplitudes, phases, frequencies):
            waves.append(singlewave(a, p, f))
        return cls(waves)
```

I find the first to be more elegant, as it doesn't require extra object creation in the `@classmethod` and the parameters of the `__init__` are directly related to the attributes of the object.  Others prefer the second as the `__init__` then relates to binding an amplitude, phase, and frequency together into a single object.

Are there some rules or conventions that suggest one is better than the other, or is it purely down to personal preference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to think of this question as *type coercion*, the two representations are equivalent and I would expect users to see that they are.

Both the approach are fine and I would expect to find them both in your interface
after all.

What I would go with is to make the `__init__` more pleasant to work with.

```py
class waveform:
    def __init__(self, *args, from=None):
        if from is None:
            from = self._peek_args(args)

        if from == "waves":
            ...
        elif from == "components":
           ...
        else:
           ...
    def _peek_args(self, args):
            # here you have to inspect the *args tuple
            # and guess what kind of input you got
            # rememeber to raise warnings and ValueError
            # to inform your user that he made mistakes
```

The catch is that now your `__init__` is variadic and you have
to write a very good piece of docs to document what is available
and how it will recognize it.

I would also mention that the user can test the input using the `_peek_args`
method, thinking of it that could be a class method so that it is easier to test.

You could even make it possible to extend this class
by looking for `__from_X` methods that the user can
plug in when he subclass.

```py
class waveform:
    def __init__(self, *args, from=None):
        try:
            ingest = gettattr(self, '__from_{}'.format(from))
            ingest(*args)
        except AttributeError as e:
            raise ValueError("from={} is not supported".format(from))
    ...
```

Comment: I would be very hesitant to do it that way.  It opens the possibility for a lot of it statements should we decide to add additional from_x options and would make documentation and clarity a lot more difficult.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it would be a lot of conditionals, the more you support the the more it makes sense to check for a `__from_x` method, I'll add that to the answer but in the end it really boils down to how easy you want it to coerced.

Comment: That's better, but I think factory methods are going to be easier to document and understand, and will be less error prone.

Comment: that's you answer then! I wouldn't bother too much for now and just put them both.

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstood the question.  I want to include both, the question is if there's a good reason for one or the other to be the `__init__`.